# regular expression for numeric value; at most 3 decimal places

Tags: javascript, regex, validation

I'm trying to validate a form using regular expressions, the conditions are:

- It has to be a numeric value
- It CAN have up to three decimal places(0,1,2 are allowed too)
- It has to be divided by a comma(,)

I already got it to work using HTML5-Patterns with this:

```
pattern='\d+(,\d{1,3})?'
```

Since patterns are not supported by IE9, I tried doing it with js:

```
var numPattern = /\d+(,\d{1,3})?/;
if(!numPattern.test(menge.val()))
{
    checkvalidate = false;
}
```

Where did I go wrong?

Examples
valid: 1,234 ; 2,00 ; 5 ; 0,1
invalid: 1,2345 ; 2.00 ; 56a

Comment: post some valid and invalid exa,ples.

Comment: If you're validating, you may want to add `^` at the beginning of your expression and `$` at the end of your expression to match the whole string.

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to start your regex with `^` and end it with `$` to make sure the entire input string/line is matched.

```
/^\d+(,\d{1,3})?$/
```

Here's a "demo" in which all your examples are valid/invalid:

https://regex101.com/r/oP5yJ4/1

(Using regex101.com to debug your regular expression patterns is often *very* useful)

Note that: (without `^` and `$`)

```
    var pattern_without = /\d+(,\d{1,3})?/;
    pattern_without.test("56a") === true; // matches, but only "56"
    pattern_without.test("1,2345") === true; // matches, but only "1,234"
```

but: (with `^` and `$`)

```
    var pattern_with = /^\d+(,\d{1,3})?$/;
    pattern_with.test("56a") === false; // no match
    pattern_with.test("1,2345") === false; // no match
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this regex:

```
/^\d+(?:,\d{1,3})*$/
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/qZ1gS8/1)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the RegExp object.

```
var str = "123545,123";
var patt = new RegExp("/^(?:\d*\,\d{1,3}|\d+)$/");
var res = patt.test(str);
```

After execution, res will be true, since str matches the pattern you're looking for,

Answer (score 0):

Try this expression:

```
\d+(,\d{3})*([.]\d{1,3})?
```

Valid examples:

```
1,200.123
1,200.12
1,200.1
1.123
1,200,222
1,200,002
```